# Create a google service account using python apiclient service

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a service account in python code.

Here is the code I have tried

```
from apiclient import discovery

flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', scope=SERVICE_SCOPE,                                           redirect_uri=config.GDRIVE_AUTHZ_REDIRECT_SERVICE_URL)

credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)

service = discovery.build('iam', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

service.projects().serviceAccount().create(name='',serviceaccountdata)
```

but it is saying `Resources does not have serviceAccount() as attribute`.

I am following [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/iam/v1/python/latest/index.html).

Let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[Per the documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/iam/v1/python/latest/iam_v1.projects.html), `projects()` has an attribute called [`serviceAccounts()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/iam/v1/python/latest/iam_v1.projects.serviceAccounts.html).

You've left the trailing `s` off.

Comment: (You've also posted on the wrong website. StackExchange would be the appropriate spot for programming questions like this, but it'd be closed there as a simple typo anyways.)